# Load external file properties with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I’m executing a jar and passing a properties file in args

```
java - jar file.jar props.properties
```

To read the properties file I’m using `java.util.Properties.load`. I want to know if there is a better way to do this with spring boot because properties file can exist in different locations or with different names but always the same properties.

I tried with `PropertySource` but I couldn’t find a way to set properties file dynamically

Comment: "*...because properties file can exist on different locations or with different names but always same properties.*" - Normally, your deployment pipeline should take care of this. Your deployment pipeline should provision the property file to some path in the file system and then start the application, passing along the location of the property file.

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
java -jar app.jar --spring.config.location=file:///Users/home/config/jdbc.properties
```

More information here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-properties-file-outside-jar